# ALTER query very slow on tiny table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've got PostgreSQL 9.2 and a tiny database with just a bit of seed data for a website that I'm working on.

The following query seems to run forever:

```
ALTER TABLE diagnose_bodypart ADD description text NOT NULL;
```

`diagnose_bodypart` is a table with less than 10 rows. I've let the query run for over a minute with no results. What could be the problem? Any recommendations for debugging this?

Comment: Sounds like some kind of lock. Do you have any connections open that access (or have accessed) the table without committing?

Comment: Have a look at the `pg_locks` view.

Comment: You're right! There were some locks. I further into it, and got rid of them. Thought, even without further inquiry, one can just close things with database connections and locks should be released. Craig Ringer: thanks for the `pg_locks` tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a column does not require rewriting a table (unless you specify a `DEFAULT`).  It is a quick operation absent any locks.  pg_locks is the place to check, as Craig pointed out.

In general the most likely cause are long-running transactions. I would be looking at what work-flows are hitting these tables and how long the transactions are staying open for.  Locks of this sort are typically transactional and so committing transactions will usually fix the problem.